# facebook-actionscript-api delete request issue

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3

I'm trying to delete a user-to-user request using facebook-actionscript-api. So far no success..I've tried the following codes:

```
//try #1
var data:Object = new Object();
data.method = 'delete';
var userid:String = "idOfTheRequestSender"; //id of the request sender
var fullrequestID:String = requestId + '_'+ userid;//requestId - id of the sent request
Facebook.api(fullrequestID, onRequestDeleteCallBack, data, "POST");
//try #2
var userid:String = "idOfTheRequestSender"; //id of the request sender
var fullrequestID:String = requestId + '_'+ userid; //requestId - id of the sent request
Facebook.deleteObject(fullrequestID, onRequestDeleteCallBack);
```

I am replacing the userid with what it should be in my app.
Neither works as the callback function parameter is always null and the request is not deleted. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

The problem is just deleting the requests, i am able to send them.

EDIT:
The problem was that i was trying to delete the request from the Facebook account that sent the request, not from the account that received the request. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
Facebook.api(fullrequestID, onRequestDeleteCallBack, {}, "DELETE");
```

Also are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but I'm gonna try and I will post the result here. I received the following error from facebook fail object:    [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"]

Comment: No luck, I've tried your code and it's not working for me. Just to make sure:  fullrequestID = requestId + "_" + userId; //userId - the id of the user who sent the request

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the userId should be the id of the user that is accepting and deleting the request, not the id of the user who sent it. Check the docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

Comment: It seems, that you can delete the request with or without the id of the user that sent the request.
So, fullrequestID = idOfTheRequest; or fullrequestId = idOfTheRequest + "_" + idOfTheUserThatSentTheRequest;
and using this function from graph-api:
Facebook.deleteObject(fullrequestID , onCallback);
And you can delete a request only when you have access token from the user that received the request, not the one who sent it.